# Quick access to elements of user control

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-8, user-controls, microsoft-metro

I have user control like this (e.g.):

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Tester.UC"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Tester"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="79" Width="380" FontSize="50" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Name="LastName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="390" Height="65" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"/>

</Grid>
```

To access this control I have to use Name and then Property.
Something liike this.

```
UC uc = new UC();
uc.LastName.Text = "text";
```

Is there any way to access it quicker? I mean...

> uc.LastName = "Text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a property in code-behind to wrap `LastName.Text`. For example

```
public string LastNameText
{
    get { return LastName.Text; }
    set { LastName.Text = value; }
}

<TextBox Name="LastName" x:FieldModifier="private"/>
```

Does it worth it? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Uhm... i think its worth when I have to use this control several times and to simplify everything. Thank you for answer it works :)
Specialy when naming each control have no sense (many other controls in my user control)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. LastName is an object of type TextBox, and "Text" is a string. You can't assign a string to a TextBox. TextBox.Text is also of type string, which is why you can assign "Text" to it. Strongly-typed object are a pretty standard principle of C#.

Theoretically you could overload the "=" operator, but this is not advised as it will make your code difficult for others to understand.